# Cannot Set Cell Container BG Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView cell setup like as BasicCell>ContentView>Container. When I set the container's background in interface builder, I get the desired darker shade of grey that I set it to. However, when I set that darker shade programmatically, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, I get a white background.

```
cell.container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20, green: 20, blue: 20, alpha: 1.0)
```

So by introducing a programmatic color setting, it suddenly ignores both the interface builder color and the programatic color. I've read several threads and tried things like using willDisplay cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let myCell = cell as! CustomTableViewCell_F2
    myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    myCell.backgroundView = nil
    myCell.container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20, green: 20, blue: 20, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

I've tried setting it in the CustomTableCell class as well. That didn't work. What's happening and how do I solve it?

Comment: Try to change your tableView's background color. If this change will be visible through cells, remove `myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()` line.

Comment: I changed the table BG color and it was visible. I then commented-out the myCell.background color line and still the container views are a white/very light shade of gray (hard to tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cell.container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20, green: 20, blue: 20, alpha: 1.0)
```

to

```
let shade: CGFloat = 0.2
cell.container.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: shade, alpha: 1.0)
```

Your color `UIColor(red: 20, green: 20, blue: 20, alpha: 1.0)` is actually white. You should provide values for color components in range 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: I already marked it correct because it fixed it but I've never heard of anything like this before. Can you explain in a little more what happened and why this fixed it?

Comment: Very simple: initializer for `UIColor` you used accepts values from 0.0 to 1.0. If you pass value that exceeds (20, for example), it will be replaced to 1.0. You can try your color in Playground and see that it white. Because you wanted gray color, I decided to use more appropriate initializer, `UIColor(white:alpha:)`.